# Round corners UIView or UIImageView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I need to add Round corners to a `UIImageView`. I found a solution from a forum, and i tried the following code;

```
UIImageView * roundedView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"wood.jpg"]];
// Get the Layer of any view
CALayer * l = [roundedView layer];
[l setMasksToBounds:YES];
[l setCornerRadius:10.0];
```

I am using iOS 5, and `setMasksToBounds:YES` and `setCornerRadius` are not found.

So is there any other way i could get round corners in my `UIImageview` ?

Comment: Have you tried assigning `l` back to the `roundedView`'s layer property?

Comment: how ? can show me what it will look like?

Comment: `roundedView.layer = l;` I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To make rounded corners on a `UIView` (or its subclass `UIImageView`), you need, like you wrote in your question, to set the cornerRadius on your layer. For example:

```
theRoundedCornersView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
```

Import the right header and it will compile:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Don't forget to link against it by adding it to your frameworks.

Answer (score 4):

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

and link against QuartzCore

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your `.h` file:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

... and the warnings will go away (the code will still work without the import). Your problem has nothing to do with iOS 5.