# Make UIView a Circle in Swift

Tags: facebook, swift, uiview, geometry

I have tried Googling my problem but cannot seem to find anything anywhere!
Basically I have a UIView which retrieves a Users Facebook Photo once they log into my app. At the moment it is a square, but I cannot figure out at all how to turn the UIView into a circle...
Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am still learning!
-Alex

This Just connects it to the UIView..

```
@IBOutlet var profilePictureView : FBProfilePictureView!
```

This sets the View as the Users FB Profile Photo

```
profilePictureView.profileID = user.objectID
```

And in app delegate.swift

```
FBProfilePictureView.self
```

Thats all the code, I set the UIView's class to be FBProfilePictureView.

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669553/round-corners-uiview-or-uiimageview

Comment: If reviewing other questions, make sure their answers are iOS 8 compliant before implementing them.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can try this

```
 profilePictureView.layer.cornerRadius = profilePictureView.frame.size.width/2
 profilePictureView.clipsToBounds = true

 profilePictureView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
 profilePictureView.layer.borderWidth = 5.0
```

Comment: The only problem is, is that it isn't an image view, rather just a normal UIView. I'm using the Facebook SDK to retrieve a user's photo and place it in the UiView

Comment: how do you place it in the uiview?

Comment: Just using the FBProfilePictureView Class

Comment: set the mask to `fbpictureview.layer.mask = clip layer`

Comment: It's just bringing up errors: "Expected Declaration" and "does not have a member named frame".

Comment: I am using storyboards and as of yet I have no code specifically for that UIView... I have my code for the rest of the View if you want, but thats just a populated tableview and stretchy header.

Comment: i just want to see the code where you add the FBProfilePictureView to the uiview

Comment: what happens if you set my code after `profilePictureView.profileID = user.objectID`

Comment: I have defined my uiImageView (100x100 points) in the storyboard and somehow the cornerRadius value I'm using (imageview.frame.size.width/2) doesn't work for all the different resolution. For iPhone 4S it makes it look like a diamond. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is anyone facing this issue in Xcode 8? Mine was working in Xcode 7 but after upgrading to Xcode 8, without touching any codes, the circle is not drawn at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining a UIBezier path as a circle and then add it as a clip to your view:

```
let circle = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: (CGPoint), radius: (CGFloat), startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2*M_PI)
```

double check, but I think arcCenter is in your superview's co-ordinate system.

To add it as a clipping path, I think it's just: (You'll have to check the docs for details):

```
circle.addClip()
```

Comment: Could you possibly help me out with that? Or just explain it a little.. I need the help to learn but i can't find any info anywhere!

Comment: Thanks for this, but I'm really still not sure where or how to implement this..

Comment: Alex - it's not something I've used myself, but this is where I'd start. I think you'll also need your own UIView (i,e, a sub-class of UIView) and the drawing and clipping will be implemented in your UIView's drawRect function.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I might just give up on this bit until i learn a bit more. Confusing the hell out of me :P